# Magic weapons add their plus to both attack and damage, and armor to AC, right?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, armor

I'm probably going blind.  I am looking for somewhere in the PHB that specifies that +1 weapons give the +1 to both attack and damage.  I see on page 196 of the PHB that it's explicitly stated that "Magic weapons, special abilities, and other factors can grant a bonus to damage." I don't see a corresponding entry under the attack rolls section that say magic weapons grant a bonus to attack as well.

Also, +1 Armor is simply +1 to AC, correct?

Sorry for the newb questions.  I've been running 3.5 forever and never played 4.  Just making sure my assumptions from 3.5 aren't messing up my first 5 game ever tomorrow!

Answer (score 29):

Magic weapons and armour are not specified in the PHB. You can find them in the DMG, pages 213 and 152 respectively. Or in the Hoard of the Dragon Queen supplement, page 2.

With that said, yes, a +X weapon gives +X to both attack and damage. +X armour gives +X to AC (on top of the AC that armour of its type provides).

Comment: This info is also available in the DM Basic Rules, in case you don't have a DM Guide book yet. http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMBasicRules_NoBackground.pdf